# How to merge duplicate values in a for loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to js and I don't understand much of codes and conditions in js.
My question is simple but I need someone to give me a good example if possible as I know what I need but it is getting hard to implement that in code.

This is my code with 2 arrays where the data is coming from.

```
blind_tmp = ''; 
for (i=0; i<@All of Blind Relationship Link.length; i++){    
    blind_tmp = blind_tmp + '<p>[**' + @All of Element Title[i] + '**](' + @All of Blind Relationship Link[i] + ')'    
};
```

What simple needed is that. I want merge records that are duplicates printed.

for example: if Blind Relationship link is `AF44` and after 6 elements this `AF44` comes again so I want both to be written like `1.AF44,2.AF44`
while now it is writing the elements how they come along

example:

```
AF11,AF22,AF33,AF44,AF55,AF66,AF77,AF44
```

so in this example you see two AF44
I want them to be written like this

```
AF11,AF22,AF33,AF44AF44,AF55,AF66,AF77
```

any help with a code example is appreciated.

Comment: you should search before you ask. if you search javascript remove duplicates from array you get your answer

Comment: How about sorting the array, then do the printing? And while printing, if current item is the same to the previous item, then don't print the comma.

Comment: object keys are always unique, so just create a new object and populate it with values from both arrays, used as keys; then get result object keys, and it's resulting merge.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to iterate through each element in the `blindRelationshipLink` and store those elements in a temporary array which will be used to check the number of occurrence of an array element.

```js
var blindRelationshipLink = ['AF11','AF22','AF33','AF11','AF44','AF44','AF55','AF66','AF77','AF11','AF22','AF11'];
var arrTemp = [];
var p = '';
blindRelationshipLink.forEach(function(arr){
var count = 0;    
arrTemp.forEach(function(a){
if(arr === a)
  count++;
  
});
arrTemp.push(arr);
if(count){
  count++;
  arr= arr + '.' + count;
}
p = p + arr + ',';  
});
alert(p);
```

You test by running the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not best but it may serve your purpose.

Here is a snippet

```
var elemArray = ['AF11', 'AF22', 'AF33', 'AF44', 'AF55', 'AF66', 'AF77', 'AF44']; // Array of elements


//A new array which which will contain elements which pass our case    
    var finalArray = [];
    elemArray.forEach(function(item) { // loop through main array
      // Check if element is present or else push the element
      if (finalArray.indexOf(item) == -1) {
        finalArray.push(item);
      } else {
        // if element is there find the index
        var getIndex = finalArray.indexOf(item);
        // remove the element, else there will be duplicate
        finalArray.splice(getIndex, 1);
        //concate the matched element
        var newElem = item + item;
        // push the element in specfic index
        finalArray[getIndex] = newElem;
      }
    })
    console.log(finalArray)
```

Current drawback with this code is what will happen if there are multiple repeated item in the main array. For example presence of `AF33` more than twice.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ny2ee0wc/)